# why glClear is clearing other instance buffer also

Tags: opengl, qtquick2

I have created two instances of Squircle item in main qml

First instance have size 500,500 alignment in center to screen

Second instance have size of screen size alignment to complete screen

Only one thing will play at a time but But during first instance player play I could not see  video because second instance player glviewport covering complete screen and its clearing because paint is getting alway its is connected to beforeRendering signal

Code:

```
.h

#ifndef SQUIRCLE_H
#define SQUIRCLE_H

#include <QtQuick/QQuickItem>
#include <QtGui/QOpenGLShaderProgram>



//! [1]
class SquircleRenderer : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    SquircleRenderer() : m_t(0), m_program(0) {}
    ~SquircleRenderer();

    void setT(qreal t) { m_t = t; }
    void setViewportSize(const QRectF &size) { m_viewportSize = size; }

public slots:
    void paint();

private:
    QRectF m_viewportSize;
    qreal m_t;
    QOpenGLShaderProgram *m_program;
};
//! [1]

//! [2]
class Squircle : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(qreal t READ t WRITE setT NOTIFY tChanged)

public:
    Squircle();

    qreal t() const { return m_t; }
    void setT(qreal t);

signals:
    void tChanged();

public slots:
    void sync();
    void cleanup();

private slots:
    void handleWindowChanged(QQuickWindow *win);

private:
    qreal m_t;
    SquircleRenderer *m_renderer;
};
//! [2]

#endif // SQUIRCLE_H
```

.cpp

```
#include "squircle.h"

#include <QtQuick/qquickwindow.h>
#include <QtGui/QOpenGLShaderProgram>
#include <QtGui/QOpenGLContext>


//! [7]
//!
Squircle::Squircle()
    : m_t(0)
    , m_renderer(0)
{
    connect(this, SIGNAL(windowChanged(QQuickWindow*)), this, SLOT(handleWindowChanged(QQuickWindow*)));
}
//! [7]

//! [8]
void Squircle::setT(qreal t)
{
    if (t == m_t)
        return;
    m_t = t;
    emit tChanged();
    if (window())
        window()->update();
}
//! [8]

//! [1]
void Squircle::handleWindowChanged(QQuickWindow *win)
{
    if (win) {
        connect(win, SIGNAL(beforeSynchronizing()), this, SLOT(sync()), Qt::DirectConnection);
        connect(win, SIGNAL(sceneGraphInvalidated()), this, SLOT(cleanup()), Qt::DirectConnection);
//! [1]
        // If we allow QML to do the clearing, they would clear what we paint
        // and nothing would show.
//! [3]
        win->setClearBeforeRendering(false);
    }
}
//! [3]

//! [6]
void Squircle::cleanup()
{
    if (m_renderer) {
        delete m_renderer;
        m_renderer = 0;
    }
}

SquircleRenderer::~SquircleRenderer()
{
    delete m_program;
}
//! [6]

//! [9]
void Squircle::sync()
{
    if (!m_renderer) {
        m_renderer = new SquircleRenderer();
        connect(window(), SIGNAL(beforeRendering()), m_renderer, SLOT(paint()), Qt::DirectConnection);
    }

    QRectF re(mapToScene(parentItem()->boundingRect().topLeft()),parentItem()->boundingRect().size());
    m_renderer->setViewportSize(re);
    m_renderer->setT(m_t);
}
//! [9]

//! [4]
void SquircleRenderer::paint()
{
    if (!m_program) {
        m_program = new QOpenGLShaderProgram();
        m_program->addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Vertex,
                                           "attribute highp vec4 vertices;"
                                           "varying highp vec2 coords;"
                                           "void main() {"
                                           "    gl_Position = vertices;"
                                           "    coords = vertices.xy;"
                                           "}");
        m_program->addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Fragment,
                                           "uniform lowp float t;"
                                           "varying highp vec2 coords;"
                                           "void main() {"
                                           "    lowp float i = 1. - (pow(abs(coords.x), 4.) + pow(abs(coords.y), 4.));"
                                           "    i = smoothstep(t - 0.8, t + 0.8, i);"
                                           "    i = floor(i * 20.) / 20.;"
                                           "    gl_FragColor = vec4(coords * .5 + .5, i, i);"
                                           "}");

        m_program->bindAttributeLocation("vertices", 0);
        m_program->link();

    }
//! [4] //! [5]
    m_program->bind();

    m_program->enableAttributeArray(0);

    float values[] = {
        -1, -1,
        1, -1,
        -1, 1,
        1, 1
    };
    m_program->setAttributeArray(0, GL_FLOAT, values, 2);
    m_program->setUniformValue("t", (float) m_t);

    glViewport(m_viewportSize.x(), m_viewportSize.y(), m_viewportSize.width(), m_viewportSize.height());

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    glScissor(m_viewportSize.x(), m_viewportSize.y(), m_viewportSize.width(), m_viewportSize.height());

    glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    m_program->disableAttributeArray(0);
    m_program->release();
}
//! [5]
```

[image]
could some one help me out of this.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: @Steve I just update the code please have a look

Answer (score 1):

> I have created two instances of opengl item

There is no such thing called "OpenGL **Item**". OpenGL just **draws** points, lines and triangles and that's it. Clearing in OpenGL means creating a blank slate to draw upon. There are no "objects" or "items" in OpenGL.

If you have several "things" drawn with OpenGL, and you want to change the appearance of only one of the "things" you have to clear the framebuffer, and redraw each and every "thing" with the one thing you want to appear altered drawn in the new state.